# ESPAsyncWebServer serve large array from RAM

Tags: arrays, json, arduino, esp32, embeddedwebserver

I am trying to serve a large float array with 8192 values from the ESP32 Heap with the ESPAsyncWebServer library for the ArduinoIDE. The µC is a ESP32 devkit c and I want to access the array with a browser.
Here is the code for the array:

```
#include "AsyncJson.h"
#include "ArduinoJson.h"
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

#define SAMPLES 8192

static float * vReal;

void setup() {
  vReal = (float *) malloc(SAMPLES * sizeof(float));
  assert(vReal != NULL);
}

void loop() {
  //Put something into the array
  for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    vReal[i] = 1.1;
  }
}
```

At the moment I use the "ArduinoJson Basic Response" and send the large array in parts of 512 values. With 1024 values I get a stack overflow in task async_tcp, if I try to access the array with the browser, so I set it to 512 values.  Here is the code for this:

```
server.on("/array1", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
AsyncResponseStream *response = request->beginResponseStream("application/json");
const size_t CAPACITY = JSON_ARRAY_SIZE(512); //Compute size of array
StaticJsonDocument<CAPACITY> vRealPart;
JsonArray array = vRealPart.to<JsonArray>();
for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
{
  vRealPart.add(vReal[i]);
}
serializeJson(vRealPart, *response); //Print to HTML
request->send(response);
});
```

I do this 16 times to serve the whole array. Later, I call the path's "/array1", "/array2", "/array3"... with JavaScript and parse the JSON. This is the output, if one of the the path's is called in a webbrowser:

```
[0.334593,0.427480,0.181299,0.066654,0.271184,0.356220,0.374454,0.235625,...]
```

This works so far for the most of the time, but I think it is very long-winded. It would be nice, if there is only one path with the whole array. It works with a static file from SPIFFS, for example:

```
server.serveStatic("/jsonArray1", SPIFFS, "/jsonArray1");
```

But it takes to much time to write the whole array to flash. Although the reading is realy fast.

I also tried the "ArduinoJson Advanced Response", but I could not get it to run with a JsonArray. Unfortunatly the examples on the GitHub page from ESPAsyncWebServer for ArduinoJson are deprecated, because they changed the syntax a bit in the new version (v6).

In a nutshell: What is the best way to serve such large arrays from the ESP32 Heap with the ESPAsyncWebServer library? The goal is to process the array later with JavaScript in a webbrowser.

Thanks for your help!

Bentiedem

PS: If it helps: I am doing a FFT with the library arduinoFFT from a motor current. Therefore I do a ADC and save the 16384 values from the analog to digital converter in an array. This array is passed to the FFT library. The output is an array with 8192 values. This result is in the heap and should be transferred to my webinterface to display the result. I want to keep the arrays in the RAM for speed. For every measurment you get a result array with 8192 values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Codebreaker007. You are right. For a simple array, which only is very long, you do not need ArduinoJson. So how are you serving your arrays with the webserver library? An example would be great. I have not a const array. I add values during my programm.

Comment: If you dont mind using the default webserver, it can do that using sendContent and setContentLength

Comment: @Ali80 Thanks, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution now which uses the chunked response. Also ArduinoJson is not used any more.
I had to shrink the buffer to get it stable (`maxLen = maxLen >> 1;`). The library gives me a wrong max. buffer length with maxLen. This could be bug.
It is much more faster than my previous solution and runs without any crashes of the µC. An array with 16384 values gets transfered in 422 ms from the µC to the webbrowser in one piece.
Here is the code for the server response:

```
server.on("/array", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request)
  {
    indexvReal = 0;
    AsyncWebServerResponse* response = request->beginChunkedResponse(contentType,
                                       [](uint8_t* buffer, size_t maxLen, size_t index)
    {
      maxLen = maxLen >> 1;
      size_t len = 0;
      if (indexvReal == 0)
      {
        len += sprintf(((char *)buffer), "[%g", vReal[indexvReal]);
        indexvReal++;
      }
      while (len < (maxLen - FLOATSIZE) && indexvReal < LEN(vReal))
      {
        len += sprintf(((char *)buffer + len), ",%g", vReal[indexvReal]);
        indexvReal++;
      }
      if (indexvReal == LEN(vReal))
      {
        len += sprintf(((char *)buffer + len), "]");
        indexvReal++;
      }
      return len;
    });
    request->send(response);
  });
```

Here is a complete example for testing purposes:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

const char *ssid = "...";
const char *password = "...";
int counter_wifi = 0;
AsyncWebServer server(80);

#define LEN(arr) ((int) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0]))
#define SAMPLES 16384
static float vReal[SAMPLES]; //Stack
uint16_t indexvReal = 0;

#define FLOATSIZE 20
const char *contentType = "application/json";
//const char *contentType = "text/plain";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    counter_wifi++;
    if (counter_wifi >= 10) { //after 5 seconds timeout - reset board (on unsucessful connection)
      ESP.restart();
    }
  }
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES; i++)
  {
    vReal[i] = random(20) * 3.2357911;
  }

  server.on("/array", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request)
  {
    indexvReal = 0;
    AsyncWebServerResponse* response = request->beginChunkedResponse(contentType,
                                       [](uint8_t* buffer, size_t maxLen, size_t index)
    {
      maxLen = maxLen >> 1;
      size_t len = 0;
      if (indexvReal == 0)
      {
        len += sprintf(((char *)buffer), "[%g", vReal[indexvReal]);
        indexvReal++;
      }
      while (len < (maxLen - FLOATSIZE) && indexvReal < LEN(vReal))
      {
        len += sprintf(((char *)buffer + len), ",%g", vReal[indexvReal]);
        indexvReal++;
      }
      if (indexvReal == LEN(vReal))
      {
        len += sprintf(((char *)buffer + len), "]");
        indexvReal++;
      }
      return len;
    });
    request->send(response);
  });

  DefaultHeaders::Instance().addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a proposal how you could use arrays compiled to flash:

```
const uint16_t SAMPLESPERSEND = 8196;
const uint8_t SAMPLESNUMSIZE = 8; // as your nums are 0.271184 so 8 chars

float myMeasureVals [SAMPLESPERSEND];
char myValueArray[SAMPLESPERSEND * (SAMPLESNUMSIZE + 1) + 2 + 1] = {'\0'};
char numBufferArray[SAMPLESNUMSIZE + 1] = {'\0'}; // Converter helper array
```

then you add with that code values

```
server.on("/array", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest * request) {
AsyncResponseStream *response = request->beginResponseStream("application/json");
  strcpy (myValueArray, "[");
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < SAMPLESPERSEND; i++) {
    if (i!=0) strcat (myValueArray, ",");
    // float myTempValue = function2GetValues(); // direct froma function
    float myTempValue = myMeasureVals [i];
    // dtostrf(floatvar, StringLengthIncDecimalPoint, numVarsAfterDecimal, charbuf);
    dtostrf(myTempValue, 2, 6, numBufferArray);
    strcat (myValueArray, numBufferArray);
  }
  strcat (myValueArray, "]");
  myValueArray [strlen(myValueArray)] = '\0'; // terminate correct
  Serial.println(myValueArray);  // Only debug
 request->send(myValueArray);
  myValueArray[0] = '\0';  // empty array for next part
});
```

Code compiles, have not tested sending could be processed that way or the chunked method has to be used. Normally I only use such large arrays only in setup and read from FileSystem. Handling here is the "same" as ArduinoJson does, but with just a few lines of code and no heap fragmentation if you need long and stable running app.
**EDIT**
My prefered solution would be to write constantly to a file in SPIFFS (see SD example data logger or [this post](https://tttapa.github.io/ESP8266/Chap16%20-%20Data%20Logging.html)) and serve the file. For ~10.000 values this is the cleanest method. How to add the brackets and comas is shown in the code above so the content of that file is one large JSON which can be quickly processed via javascript. And by using eg 10 different log files you have the possibility to recover in case of network errors or similar

Comment: I tested the code, but I get the following error: "invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]" for the request->send. Here is my complete testcode: https://pastebin.com/xjYGRFQw

Comment: It works only for the first part of the array. I think it is not possible to use more than one request->send. I tried to write my array to flash, but this method is very slow. Also I do not understand how to write constantly to a file in SPIFFS.

Comment: Again I get only the first part of the array. Maybe it helps if I explain my project in more detail. I am doing a FFT with the library arduinoFFT from a motor current. Therefore I do a ADC and save the 16384 values from the analog to digital converter in an array. This array is passed to the FFT library. The output is an array with 8192 values. This result is in the heap and should be transferred to my webinterface to display the result. I want to keep the array in the RAM for speed. For every measurment you get a result array with 8192 values.

Comment: I don't necessary want to log my result array to the flash. I tried this one time to test, if it is possible to load a large array with 8192 from the flash. It is working, but the writing time to flash is to long. My old solution is much faster and that is the one, I want to improve. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Output is "[0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,...]" 512 times. I see only one loop. In the first version you got 2.

Comment: You have not copied the new vars on my MCU this outputs 8196

Comment: Sorry. Now I got a compiling error "DRAM segment data does not fit." Thats why I went to the heap solution with "malloc()".

Comment: That will not run for long though perhaps sombody else has an Idea for the monster array

Comment: I don't have heap problems. The webserver runs stable for many hours. Although the project is not realy for long term measurments. I thought that maybe "Respond with content using a callback" or "Chunked Response" is the right thing to use. But stil, many thanks for your help!